# What does the value "e" mean in doPost(e) and some other functions?

Tags: google-apps-script

Following is the code, I'm referring to:

```
function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e);
 MailApp.sendEmail(TO_ADDRESS, "Contact Form Submitted",
                      JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
    record_data(e);
    return ContentService 
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Value of "e" is not declared earlier but still "e" is used to passing data from one function to another.

I recently started learning app script (JS) and knows a bit about how the declaration works. Here's my understanding.

To get defined result, we should pass the parameters in functions if it's declared as variable before like:

```
var e = "something";
function doPost(e) {here goes the further code};
```

But in the initial code, the value "e" had no value in it as it's not defined. Is my understanding perfect?

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments are assigned values **when the function is called**.

In this example:

> ```
> var e = "something";
> function doPost(e) {here goes the further code};
> ```

You define two **different** variables, both called `e`. One is outside the function and is assigned the value `"something"`. The other is inside the function and may or may not get a value if and when that function is **called**. The code samples you provided don't call the function (or do anything else with it), so we have no way of telling what that value is.

```
doPost("Foo"); // the inside-`e` is "Foo"
doPost(e); // the inside-`e` has the same value as the outside-`e` (at least unless and until you assign a new value to it inside the function) 
doPost(); // the inside-`e` is `undefined`
```

---

The variable name `e` is *traditionally* used to hold [Event objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event), which typically get passed to a function which is assigned as an event listener.

Event listeners are usually triggered by *things from outside the program*, like the user clicking a mouse button, so you would rarely write the code that assigns the value.

e.g. in a webpage:

```
document.addEventListener("click", doPost);
```

In this case `addEventListener` is a function written by the browser vendor (not by the page author). It (or other code built-in to the browser) will call `doPost` and pass a value for `e`, so you never see that code. You just know that `doPost` will be called with an Event object if the user ever clicks.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `e` is variable declaration and you assign a value to that by passing arguments to the function. But even if your function expects an `e` and you don't pass one that code is executed perfectly.

Because of the nature of Javascript there are cases where the functions you declare are executed from other functions and they might pass some values there.

A signature of a function such as `function doPost(e)` can also be invoked with additional arguments.

eg : `doPost(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);`

And you can access all of that from `arguments` variable within the function.

```
doPost(){ console.log(arguments); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `e` means raised event like in e.g.:

```
$(document).on('click', '.el', function (e) {});
```

In this code `e` will contain click event.

---

In your code code just check who calls this `doPost()`. Like `doPost.apply(this, [e])`

---

Keep in mind that you can call `doPost()` without actually passing `e` to function and it will not throw any error. Than `typeof e` inside function will return `undefined`